# Use VS2012 JavaScript debugging with Chrome (similar to IE)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012

With VS2012 and IE9 I can use the VS2012 JavaScript debugger from within VS2012 (similar to C#, ..). When I switch the browser to Chrome, I loose the ability to do so. I could switch to the the Chrome intrinsic debugger.

[image: Chrome as browser]

**But, is there a way to get debugging with Chrome working with VS2012 (similat to IE)?**

Example: Breakpoint hit with IE, but not with Chrome as browser.

[image: Breakpoint]

Remark: No duplicate of [Debugging Websites with Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189353/debugging-websites-with-google-chrome) which is about .net debugging. I am not using any ASP.net, only JavaScript

Comment: This appears to require much more cooperation between Microsoft and Google than I would expect either would be willing to offer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it's absolutely impossible to debug JS in Chrome from VS, because it's a completely different internal engine. May be somebody will write a plugin for VS, but right now it's not possible.

Comment: exactly. no addition required.

Answer (score 6):

inside a javascript place a "debugger;" command and refresh the page.

works in **CHROME** v30> and IE 10>

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function LoginEstabelecimento() {

            var form = $('form#formLoginEstabelecimento');

            debugger;

           ... SOME REST OF CODE ...

        };
</script>
```

Comment: no way, how would it work? does not for me for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can always right click the page in Chrome, choose 'inspect element' and use chrome's built-in javascript debugger.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible. See [this](http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/JavaScript-debugging-in-VisualStudio-with-Chrome) page for how, but in a nutshell (using Windows 10 1607, Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3):

1. Close all Chrome windows (this is important)
2. From the Run prompt "chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222" (without quotes)
3. In Visual Studio, start your application with Chrome as the browser. This opens your page in a new tab.
4. In Visual Studio, with the application still running, click Debug -> Attach to Process... -> select the Chrome process that is running you page.
5. This should attach to the process without any error and your break points in Visual Studio should now get hit.

Also, see [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6205061-provide-integrated-javascript-debugging-in-firefox?page=1&per_page=20) page which confirms this feature will be added to a future Visual Studio release.