# VS 2013 - Symbols are not loading on Attach to Process with Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to use "Attach to Process" feature of VS 2013 with chrome. My website is hosted on IIS on local machine. I am not able to debug as symbols are not getting loaded in server side. If I run using F5 then debugging goes smooth.

Message is "The breakpoint will not currently hit. No symbols have loaded for this document".
Please suggest!!

Comment: You are probably using the wrong debug engine.  The default one is for native code and that's not going to do much for Chrome.  In the Attach dialog be sure to click the Select button after picking the process.  Select the "Debug these code types" radio button.  Not actually sure what is appropriate for Chrome, I assume it is Webkit.

Comment: There is no option like Webkit. Options visible are Native, Managed,Script, Silverlight, T-SQL, Workflow, Managed Compatibility Mode,

Comment: Script sounds like a good choice when you debug code that runs in Chrome.  Hard to guess when you don't tell us what you actually want to debug.  Or maybe you meant to actually debug the code that runs on the web server, so should have picked the IIS process instead.

Comment: I have to debug code running on web server. Tried to attach using IIS as well. If I run it directly from code, it works.

Comment: Edit your question to make it clear that you never actually meant to attach to Chrome, only way you are going to get somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried specify both managed and native code from the "Attach to:" "Select..."  select code type dialog? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: Hi Alex..I tried using both..but no luck

Comment: @Hemendra, Like this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189353/debugging-websites-with-google-chrome, if you debug the web app which was deployed to the IIS, you just need to attach to the w3wp.exe process(Not the Chrome browser). Even if you debug your app with script locally, you also don't need to attach to it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/, actually Visual Studio is attaching to Chrome using the remote debugging protocol. If I have misunderstood this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: @Hemendra, Could you debug your app now? Would you please share the latest information here?

Comment: No..Still I am not able to debug